# Disable ASP.NET Server Validation on form submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms, postback

I have an ASP.NET Linkbutton with the OnClientScript property set to open a popup where the user can search for some values which then should be taken over to the opening ASP.NET Page. To overtake the values from my popup to the opening page I manually force an post-back vie JavaScript:

```
window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
```

This is executed after the workflow on the popup is finished

This works as the page which opened the popup will be loaded again (Page_Load is executed with IsPostBack = true and the values from the popup are overtaken via SessionState variables).

However the problem is that forcing a post-back from JavaScript like this will also force a validation on the opening page. For Buttons which use the OnClick - event to perform the post-back you can simply set

```
CausesValidation = false
```

and all validation is disabled for this post-back. The only way I found to circumvent this problem is to manually disable all the problematic validators somewhere in Page_Load for this particular workflow and then re-enable them later on. This is however quite ugly as there are many validators on the page and the logic when to en/disable each validator is not simple.

Is there an easy way to just disable Server side validation for just one post-back (without disabling the validators manually). What I want is something like

```
CausesValidation = false
```

which can be set in Page_Load on the server side. I don´t think there is a way to disable server validation from JavaScript, is there?

EDIT:

So to make this (hopefully) more clear, I have a Linkbutton on my aspx page like this:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LB1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
  OnClientClick="window.open(xyz.aspx?...)"
```

On xzy.aspx after some user workflow the following line is executed:

```
window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
```

This causes a postback on the page with the LinkButton. As a postback also all the validators are evaluated and the page may get invalidated even though the user didn´t apply the save button. So I want to find a way to prevent this validation in case the postback is caused not by an OnClick event from ASP.NET control but by something like the above JavaScript.

In the definition of the Linkbutton above, setting CausesValidation="False" doesn´t help because the postback is not caused by the Linkbutton itself (only OnClientClick attribute is set and the postback / form submit is caused by some javascript on the popup)

So what I really need is a way to tell ASP.NET not to perform any validation in case my postback is called by the above javascript form submit instead of an ASP.NET Control.

The hard way to do this would be to disable all validators manually (via Page.Validators or smth.) for this particular workflow and then on the next postback reenable them again, but as mentioned the Validator logic is very complex and I want to prevent rerunning all the initialization logic for the validators.

Answer (score 0):

all the validators in ASP.NET have an `EnableClientScript` property which you can set to true or false based on your needs. If you set it to false, you will be able to perform a postback using javascript and then trigger validation in your code behind.

Comment: This does not work, the validation is still executed. What I want is a way to prevent every validation on a postback which is triggered by form-submit via javascript. (independend on any validators)

Comment: Can you attach the code then so we can help? Not much to go with just now.